# Running ansible-playbook using Python API

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-runner

How can I run a playbook in python script? What is the equivalent of the following using ansible module in python:

```
ansible -i hosts dbservers -m setup
ansible-playbook -i hosts -vvvv -k site.yml
```

I was looking at their documenation in http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html but they have very limited examples.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*Deprecation Notice: This post doesn't work as of Ansible 2. The API was changed.*

This is covered in the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html) under "Python API."

For example, `ansible -i hosts dbservers -m setup` is implemented via:

```
import ansible.runner

runner = ansible.runner.Runner(
   module_name='setup',
   module_args='',
   pattern='dbservers',
)
dbservers_get_facts = runner.run()
```

There are a bunch of non-documented parameters in the `__init__` method of Runner (from `ansible.runner`).  There's [too many to list inline](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/release1.8.4/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py#L109-L162), but I've included some of the parameters in this post as a guess to what you're specifically looking for.

```
class Runner(object):
    ''' core API interface to ansible '''

    # see bin/ansible for how this is used...

    def __init__(self,
        host_list=C.DEFAULT_HOST_LIST,      # ex: /etc/ansible/hosts, legacy usage
        module_path=None,                   # ex: /usr/share/ansible
        module_name=C.DEFAULT_MODULE_NAME,  # ex: copy
        module_args=C.DEFAULT_MODULE_ARGS,  # ex: "src=/tmp/a dest=/tmp/b"
        ...
        pattern=C.DEFAULT_PATTERN,          # which hosts?  ex: 'all', 'acme.example.org'
        remote_user=C.DEFAULT_REMOTE_USER,  # ex: 'username'
        remote_pass=C.DEFAULT_REMOTE_PASS,  # ex: 'password123' or None if using key
        remote_port=None,                   # if SSH on different ports
        private_key_file=C.DEFAULT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, # if not using keys/passwords
        sudo_pass=C.DEFAULT_SUDO_PASS,      # ex: 'password123' or None
        ...
        sudo=False,                         # whether to run sudo or not
        sudo_user=C.DEFAULT_SUDO_USER,      # ex: 'root'
        module_vars=None,                   # a playbooks internals thing
        play_vars=None,                     #
        play_file_vars=None,                #
        role_vars=None,                     #
        role_params=None,                   #
        default_vars=None,                  #
        extra_vars=None,                    # extra vars specified with he playbook(s)
        is_playbook=False,                  # running from playbook or not?
        inventory=None,                     # reference to Inventory object
        ...
        su=False,                           # Are we running our command via su?
        su_user=None,                       # User to su to when running command, ex: 'root'
        su_pass=C.DEFAULT_SU_PASS,
        vault_pass=None,
        ...
        ):
```

For instance, the above command that specifies a sudo user and pass would be:

```
runner = ansible.runner.Runner(
   module_name='setup',
   module_args='',
   pattern='dbservers',
   remote_user='some_user'
   remote_pass='some_pass_or_python_expression_that_returns_a_string'
)
```

For playbooks, look into [playbook.PlayBook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/release1.8.4/lib/ansible/playbook/__init__.py#L42-L84), which takes a similar set of initializers:

```
class PlayBook(object):
    '''
    runs an ansible playbook, given as a datastructure or YAML filename.
    ...
    '''

    # *****************************************************

    def __init__(self,
        playbook         = None,
        host_list        = C.DEFAULT_HOST_LIST,
        module_path      = None,
        ....
```

and can be executed with the `.run()` method. e.g.:

```
from ansible.playbook import PlayBook
pb = PlayBook(playbook='/path/to/book.yml, --other initializers--)
pb.run()
```

more robust usage can be found in the [`ansible-playbook` file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/release1.8.4/bin/ansible-playbook).

As far as I know, translating playbooks to Python modules is a bit more involved, but the documentation listed above should get you covered and you can reuse the YAML parser built into Ansible to convert playbooks to variables.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer how to run a playbook, but instead an individual task. There is an `ansible.playbook.Playbook` class with a `run` method as well which I think the OP is asking about - I know it's what I'm trying to find :D

Comment: ansible.playbook.Playbook calls to runner for execution (see `is_playbook` in ansible.runner), but good point.  updating answer now.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also found a good example in (where else?!) the GitHub repo with their [ansible-playbook command](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/bin/ansible-playbook#L186) --- (edit: whoops, you pointed that out already :D )

Comment: @fideloper happy to help.  my typical path in extending Ansible is to just hop around in the source or to just kick off pdb and follow it -- Ansible's code base is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 39):

Just a quick code update that works on 2.8.3,

```
from ansible import context
from ansible.cli import CLI
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager

loader = DataLoader()

context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh',
                    module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='xxx', private_key_file=None,
                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=True,
                    become_method='sudo', become_user='root', verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None)

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=('/xxx/inventory_file',))

variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=['/xxx/playbook.yml'], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, passwords={})

results = pbex.run()
```

Comment: Great answer. The ansible documentation is not very helpful on this, and your answer is the only place I could find to actually work, thanks!

Comment: how can we pass the group_vars files?

Comment: Never mind; Folder didn't contain them; I was running in docker container

Comment: So much more helpful then anything in the official docs. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 14):

I have answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368044/how-to-use-ansible-2-0-python-api-to-run-a-playbook/35507743#35507743)
Posting this here cause posting links is discouraged in the community. Hope it helps.

The documentation is surprisingly lacking and you'll have to get started [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py)

That being said, here is a quick script I hacked together that manages to run a playbook.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import Inventory
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor

loader = DataLoader()

inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, sources='/home/slotlocker/hosts2')
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
playbook_path = '/home/slotlocker/ls.yml'

if not os.path.exists(playbook_path):
    print '[INFO] The playbook does not exist'
    sys.exit()

Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check','diff'])
options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='slotlocker', private_key_file=None, ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=True, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False, diff=False)

variable_manager.extra_vars = {'hosts': 'mywebserver'} # This can accomodate various other command line arguments.`

passwords = {}

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords=passwords)

results = pbex.run()
```

Comment: How do we get all relevant group vars for the playbook?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, helped me a lot, for everyone using paramiko_ssh please note, that you have to have ** `ssh_common_args=''` and `ssh_extra_args=''` not None **, otherwise you will get an exception: _TypeError: sequence item: expected string, NoneType found_ cost me a bit of time and surfing the code to get that straight.

Comment: For Ansible 2.6 (2.6.8) there is API change, you should change Inventory to InventoryManager so.... from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager      
 and inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader ...

Comment: variable_manager._extra_vars = {'hosts': 'mywebserver'} for Ansible version greater than 2.8 as per https://github.com/grycap/im/commit/18f79f9b7328f144da771f413f571b7e87c7b5d4

Answer (score 6):

Ansible provides the `ansible-runner` Python package ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-runner/), [GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner)), which can be used for this.

Usage example from the [documentation](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#usage-examples):

```py
import ansible_runner
r = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='/tmp/demo', playbook='test.yml')
print("{}: {}".format(r.status, r.rc))
# successful: 0
for each_host_event in r.events:
    print(each_host_event['event'])
print("Final status:")
print(r.stats)
```

Comment: `ansible-runner` requires `ansible` executable

Answer (score 3):

Based on **vigilander**'s answer, I took the liberty to upload a pkg to pypi and now you can use this simple ansible runner:

Just pip install [ansible-playbook-runner](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-playbook-runner/) and run:

```
from ansible_playbook_runner import Runner

Runner(['inventory_path'], 'playbook_path').run()
```

Comment: Is the project live? Can you share the code? A shame that Ansible's has a really poor interface for python, even though the API is 100% ready.

Comment: I don't maintain it currently. What I uploaded is what's going to be there for the foreseeable future

Comment: Mind posting a link for the source? Could only find it on PyPi but not on github

Comment: Don't think I uploaded it... You can take them from the wheel after you install