# How to run ansible module in python

Tags: python, ansible

Here is my code:
I am not able to run a ansible module using python.
How to pass a inventory file for which this command is running. I am not able to run it for my inventory.
Do I need to do something else ?
Here is my ansible command:

```
ansible all -i /home/ubuntu/extra -m 'debug' -a 'var=hostvars'
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import ansible.runner
import ansible.playbook
import ansible.inventory

hosts = ["10.12.11.101"]
example_inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(hosts)
pm = ansible.runner.Runner( module_name = 'debug', module_args = 'vars=hostvars', timeout = 5, inventory = example_inventory, subset = 'all')
out = pm.run()
print json.dumps(out, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: what do you mean by you are not able to run it for your inventory ? what was the error occured ? have you tried passing your inventory file to`ansible.inventory.Inventory` ?

Comment: its a python import error, how did you installed ansible ?

Comment: And , post the error occured along with your question, it is the way questions are asked in SO.

Comment: How to pass inventory file? global name 'inventory' is not defined

Comment: you can pass the inventory file just like you did with your `hosts` list.
just pass the path to your inventory file. make sure you have installed ansible correctly. i suggest use `pip`.

Comment: I installed it correctly. But no idea how to pass a -i file on which I run this ansible

Comment: have you tried passing your inventory file to `ansible.inventory.Inventory`?

Comment: When I give a path as inventory="/home/ubuntu/common_shared" it gives me error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94299/discussion-between-frank-and-kohi).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running ansible-playbook using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590039/running-ansible-playbook-using-python-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the inventory file path to `ansible.runner.Runner()`

And for getting `group-names` and `host-names` , you should pass `var=hostvars`, not `vars=hostvars`

Your code would look like this,

```
import json
import ansible.runner
import ansible.playbook
import ansible.inventory

example_inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory('path/to/your/inventory')
pm = ansible.runner.Runner( module_name = 'debug', module_args = 'var=hostvars', timeout = 5, inventory = example_inventory, subset = 'all')
out = pm.run()
print json.dumps(out, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

and your output

```
{'contacted': {'ip-address': {'invocation': {'module_args': u'var=hostvars',
    'module_complex_args': {},
    'module_name': 'debug'},
   'var': {u'hostvars': {'group_names': ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'],
     'groups': {'group1': ['ip-address'],
      'all': ['ip-address'],
      'group2': ['ip-address'],
      'group3': ['ip-address'],
      'ungrouped': []},
     'inventory_hostname': 'ip/hostname',
     'inventory_hostname_short': 'hostname-short'}},
   'verbose_always': True}},
 'dark': {}}
```

Comment: You are right. One thing I was doing wrong is using vars in place of var.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it is best to go through the `ansible_runner` package, (https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner), instead of importing `ansible` directly. See my answer to [Running ansible-playbook using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590039/running-ansible-playbook-using-python-api/64259360#64259360) for a complete example.