# Python API Ansible verbosity setting

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

I tried to setup Ansible using Python API from the following site.

https://serversforhackers.com/c/running-ansible-2-programmatically

The question at hand is as follows:
**How to alter verbosity programmatically in ansible. The codes below seems to not work to adjust the verbosity of the output.**

```
# Set global verbosity
self.display = Display()
self.display.verbosity = self.options.verbosity
# Executor appears to have it's own 
# verbosity object/setting as well
playbook_executor.verbosity = self.options.verbosity
```

It has been pretty successful (ansible 2.3.0) thus far except verbosity settings. As the codes are in the website, I'll not post my codes here since it is exactly the same. I have tried to check the source code of ansible but it seems to be quite difficult to look through how the options are used. (i looked at display.py, playbook_executor.py, play_context.py, etc...)

note: for users who use the same code, please set the skip_tags and tags to '' for it to work in versions > 2.2.0.

Comment: Also, regarding *"As the codes are in the website, I'll not post my codes here since it is exactly the same."* - can you post your code anyway for the benefit of future readers, in case the site goes down?  Or people who otherwise don't trust links like "serversforhackers.com"? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really dirty hack how to apply verbosity when using Ansible API 2:

```
import __main__ as main
from ansible.utils.display import Display


display = Display(verbosity=4)
setattr(main, 'display', display)
```

Confirmed to work in Ansible `v2.4`.

This answer is based on https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/95763/ansible.utils.display.Display and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47639200/4533625.