# Append role to a playbook in Ansible 2.0 Python API

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-api

Building on this question [How to use Ansible 2.0 Python API to run a Playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368044/how-to-use-ansible-2-0-python-api-to-run-a-playbook)

How can I create an instance of PlaybookExecutor class and append an Ansible role that will be executed when pbex.run() is called?

This is an example Playbook ls.yml - Note roles is an empty list.

```
---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  roles: []
```

This is the code to run the playbook using the API:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor

variable_manager = VariableManager()
loader = DataLoader()

inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager,  host_list='/home/slotlocker/hosts2')
playbook_path = '/home/slotlocker/ls.yml'

if not os.path.exists(playbook_path):
    print '[INFO] The playbook does not exist'
    sys.exit()

Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check'])
options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='slotlocker', private_key_file=None, ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=True, become_method=None, become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False)

variable_manager.extra_vars = {'hosts': 'mywebserver'} # This can accomodate various other command line arguments.`

passwords = {}

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords=passwords)

results = pbex.run()
```

In pre Ansible 2.0 - specifically in 1.7 I was able to simply append the name of the role as follows (skipping imports) and call the run method:

```
pb = ansible.playbook.PlayBook(
        playbook='ls.yml',
        callbacks=playbook_cb,
        runner_callbacks=runner_cb,
        stats=stats,
        host_list=host_list,
        private_key_file=p_key_file,
        check=True,
        forks=1,
        extra_vars={'remote_user': remote_user}
    )

**pb.playbook[0]['roles'].append(role_name)**

pb.run()
```

I want to replicate this in Ansible 2.0.

thanks