# Running ansible-playbook with Python API

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to launch an ansible playbook from a python script but I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_runner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'
```

I'm using one of the code that I found on this link [Running ansible-playbook using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590039/running-ansible-playbook-using-python-api) and here is my ansible location:

```
  ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

Could you help me figure out why my pythom program doesn't found the ansible module?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore that.
A figured out that I had two python releases installed on the server: Python2.7 and 3.6.
The Python3.6 directory doesn't have the module installed so I need to launch the program using Python2.7.