# Python script sub directory path in Azure Functions

Tags: python, ansible, azure-functions, ansible-runner

I currently have a python project that contains python script, and azure function files.
This is the structure of the project:

```
├── ansible-deploy-pipelines.yml
├── ansibleazurefunc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── function.json
│   └── sample.dat
├── config
│   ├── env
│   │   ├── envvars
│   │   ├── extravars
│   │   ├── passwords
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   └── ssh_key
│   ├── inventory
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── project
│       ├── roles
│       │   └── linux-vms
│       │       ├── README.md
│       │       ├── defaults
│       │       │   └── main.yml
│       │       ├── handlers
│       │       │   └── main.yml
│       │       ├── meta
│       │       │   └── main.yml
│       │       ├── tasks
│       │       │   └── main.yml
│       │       ├── tests
│       │       │   ├── inventory
│       │       │   └── test.yml
│       │       └── vars
│       │           └── main.yml
│       └── test.yml
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
├── proxies.json
├── requirements.txt
└── scripts
    ├── deploy_config.py
    ├── hosts
    └── playbook.yml
```

The python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor


loader = DataLoader()

def main()
    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='hosts')
    variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
    playbook_path = 'playbook.yml'

    if not os.path.exists(playbook_path):
        print("[INFO] The playbook does not exist")
        sys.exit()

    Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check','diff'])
    options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh', module_path=None, forks=100, remote_user='devadmin', private_key_file='../config/env/ssh_key', ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=True, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', verbosity=None, check=False, diff=False)


    passwords = {}

    tp = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords=passwords)

    results = tp.run()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Azure function **init**.py file:

```
import logging 
import json

import azure.functions as func
from scripts import deploy_config


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python script for calling Ansible playbook.')

    deploy_config.main()
    
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Ansible deploy - Completed")
```

The entire project is deployed using azure pipelines, which successfully complete the build and release pipelines. However, the script fails to execute. I have had the script executed standalone to confirm it works.

The confusion for me is how to configure the path to the playbook.yml and hosts files within Azure function. I am unable to debug within azure functions to see any possible errors that might be helpful.

How do I set this path within Azure functions? The following paths obviously work locally:

```
private_key_file='../config/env/ssh_key'

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='hosts')

playbook_path = 'playbook.yml'
```

I'm quite new to Azure functions, but I believe setting the path correctly might be the solution to this issue. I am not sure what I'm missing.

I have used the following links for references:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html

https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface/

[Running ansible-playbook using Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590039/running-ansible-playbook-using-python-api#27597987)

Comment: What is actually wrong with calling the playbook directly on the command line (with `os` or `subprocess`)? Please pay attention to the notes on top of the [ansible api doc page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html): `This API is intended for internal Ansible use. Ansible may make changes to this API at any time that could break backward compatibility with older versions of the API. Because of this, external use is not supported by Ansible. If you want to use Python API only for executing playbooks or modules, consider ansible-runner first.`

Comment: @Zeitounator, it executes just fine on the command line. And I haven't tried using subprocess, which just might work.
And yes, not sure how I missed this part `If you want to use Python API only for executing playbooks or modules, consider ansible-runner first`  on the API doc!